# codeigniter how do I edit or delete the rows in table

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-table, edit, crud

How do I get the user id of the respective rows of table to edit or delete? My table has an action column that have edit and delete button.
This is my view:

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
   <tr>
     <td>First Name</td>
     <td>Last Name</td>
     <td>Address Name</td>
     <td>Action</td>
   </tr>
  <?php foreach($results as $row): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row->first_name; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row->last_name; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row->address; ?></td>
      <td><a href="" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
      <a href="<?php echo base_url()."main/deleteclient" ?>"                                       
          class="btn btn-danger"
              onclick="return confirm
              ('Are you sure  to Delete?')">Delete</a></td>

                </tr>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>

 </table>
```

Comment: Does the query return the ID too?

Comment: You should not use a link (a GET request) to delete content. Instead use a form and POST.

Comment: Can you post your controller and model?

Comment: Do you have an `id` within your `results`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()."main/deleteclient" ?>"                                       
          class="btn btn-danger"
          onclick="return confirm
          ('Are you sure  to Delete?')">Delete</a>
```

to

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()."main/deleteclient?id=".$row->id ?>"                                       
          class="btn btn-danger"
          onclick="return confirm
          ('Are you sure  to Delete?')">Delete</a>
```

And then from your PHP script check if the variable "id" exists in your $_GET and handle the deletion.

Still working on formatting the answer.

Comment: have you selected the id field( the primary key)?? in the model?? if you have selected that field then it would show up here...

Comment: This is my model:public function getall(){
   $query= $this->db->query("select * from client");
   return $query->result();
  }

Comment: ok the query seems fine.. are you geting the result?? i mean the firstname ,lastname etc?

Comment: you want to delete it via ajax?? or you want to redirect it to the page and catch the Id and then delete and return back to this list page??

Comment: ok then its simple create a function deleteclient and in that take the value wich comes at the last as the segment.. since you pass the value at the end it would be something like deleteclient/2 or deleteclient/4 ..... these are just the ids of the row. get this and fire the delete query and put redirect code to return to this  page again...

Comment: sorry i didnt get the idea, could you please post the controller code :D

Answer (score 0):

```
    As like you are getting other table values like first name and last name there should be (if you gave an primary id) an id for each row. So you can get that id for each row and send it to your delete function by URL.

     <?php foreach($results as $row): ?>
           <tr> 

                <td><?php echo $row->first_name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->last_name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->address; ?></td>
                <td><a href="" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>

<a href="<?= base_url();?>main/deleteclient/<?= $row->id;?>"></a>                                      
                  class="btn btn-danger"
                  onclick="return confirm
                  ('Are you sure  to Delete?')">Delete</a></td>

                    </tr>
                     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

ADD $row->id IN YOUR  TAGS and this will take the row id to your deleteclient function in your main controller when you click that button.

Comment: Check this link out. you will get how the url system works in codeigniter. If you need further help after reading this then let me know. :) https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: The article was helpful, but i still did not figure out to get the user id in controller.

Comment: suppose you have a controller named main and in that controller you have a function deleteclient. so the would be like this- class Main extends CI_Controller{ public function deleteclient($id) { //your mysql query to delete the id. } }. when your user will click <a href="<?= base_url();?>main/deleteclient/<?= $row->id;?>"></a> , it will trigger main controller, deleteclient function with $row->id as the argument $id of deleteclient($id) function.

Answer (score 0):

thank y'all so much.. This is how i deleted rows. Let me know if it there are better ways to do it!

```
   view: 

    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tr>
       <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Address</td>
         <td>Citizen Number</td>
       <td>Action</td>
   </tr>
    <?php foreach($results as $row): ?>
   <tr> 

   <td><?php echo $row->first_name; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row->last_name; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row->address; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row->citizen_no; ?></td>
  <td><a href="" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a> 
  <a href="<?php echo base_url().
  "main/deleteclient?id=".$row->client_id ?  >" 
  class="btn btn-danger" 
 onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Delete?')">Delete</a></td>

 </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

 </table>  

    controller:
      public function deleteclient(){
     if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $this->load->model('members');
        $this->members->row_delete($id);
        redirect('main/viewclient');}
 }
   model:
  public function row_delete(){
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $this->db->where('client_id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('client');
    }
```